# i am tryng to put firebase in my project i have tried everthing, it returns a error code 500

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import '@react-native-firebase/auth'


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "your-key-here",
  authDomain: "your-name-here.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "your-id-here",
  storageBucket: "your-name-here.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "0000000000",
  appId: "000000000",
  measurementId: "G-XXXXXXXXXXX"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export default fi
```

rebase;

it returns with However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\brock\Desktop\react-native\insta-app\node_modules\firebase\index`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

I am trying to create a login system it doesnt seem to wanna work

Comment: brock - be careful with posting credentials like this.

Comment: all of the credentials are still visible as edits can be seen by any one  so you better delete the question to prevent any safety breach .

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import "@firebase/auth";
import "@firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "your-key-here",
  authDomain: "your-name-here.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "your-id-here",
  storageBucket: "your-name-here.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "0000000000",
  appId: "000000000",
  measurementId: "G-XXXXXXXXXXX"
};
  
  if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
     firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }
```

Always works for me.

Comment: careful with posting full credentials like this. Anonymize for your safety.